# Download file from firefox using autoit

Tags: autoit

I try to download file using Autoit from Firefox 28.0.

I try to download a exe file,popup flashed but autoit window info tool cannot recognize the save button.

how can i automate this.

[image]

My scripts looks like

```
Local $hWnd=WinActivate("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]")
WinWaitActive($hWnd)
;MsgBox(1,$hWnd,$hWnd)
;ControlClick($hWnd,"","Save")
ControlClick($hWnd,"&Save File","")
;WinClose("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]")
```

how can i automate this......

Comment: Why automating? Try to use InetGet instead.

Comment: thanks for comment.Actually I need this because to simulate the user point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Right now both of your `ControlClick` attempts are incorrect. The correct syntax is `ControlClick(Window title or handle, *window* text, control *id*, ...)`. Look at the helpfile and examples for it to see what you're not doing right currently.

The firefox download dialog is a little tricky, googling gives a lot of results for people who have tried to do the same thing and struggled.

The easiest method is to click the window at the coordinates of the button. `ControlClick` can be used for this (simply leave the control id blank). The AutoIt window info tool should give `ControlClick` coords when you try and select where the button is.

That method does assume that the button is always in the same place, which is not necessarily the case. Alternatives are to use `ControlSend` to send the `Alt+S` combination (or whatever it is for that button).

And finally, it's worth mentioning [the IUIAutomation framework](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/) which has shown to be very reliable for automating windows that aren't using standard winapi controls.

Comment: Thanks for your help....actually I write the controlclink  in this way because to make it dynamic and it is working correctly because if I pass the title then it may not work if title was changed or different download application window then it does not work so I pass the handle.

Comment: @saba, it wasn't the passing of the handle I was talking about, it was the incorrect use of control id and window text parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do is as follows on mozilla:

Use the following code on `autoit.au3` file

1. ControlFocus ( "MozillaDialogClass", "", "" )
2. Sleep(10)
3. Send("{ENTER}")

Execute the same file in selenium using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Balaji\\Desktop\\autoit.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to download a file in Firefox using AutoIt.

```
WinWait("[TITLE:Opening ; CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]","", 10)

If WinExists("[TITLE:Opening ; CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]") Then

    ; Perform keyboard ALT key + s key to select Save File Radio button using keyboard shortcut.    
    ControlFocus ( "[TITLE:Opening ; CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]","", "" )    
    Send("!s")

    ; Wait for 2 seconds    
    Sleep(2000)

    ; Press Keyboard ENTER button.    
    Send("{ENTER}")

EndIf
```